# How are the variables populated in this Javacript snippet plus a couple of other questions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a backend developer but would like to figure out this snippet of javacript. I've put some comments on the pieces I get, but have boldfaced questions for the parts I don't.

```
function transformData (output) {

    // QUESTION: 

    // what the difference between "{}" and "[]" below? 
    const filteredData = {};

    const Statistics = [];

    // this is an array of the codes
    const NORCA_CODE = [
    'QFV1D_START_CHARACTER_CORRECTED',
    'QFV1D_STOP_CHARACTER_CORRECTED',
    'QFV1D_BUFFER_DECODING_FAILED'
    ]


   // this is to create Series 0, which is the X axis. It just has the systems, e.g, 01, 02,
   // etc. 

  /* Series 0 */

    // Here it's creating data0. 
    // It's going to use an array function to create a set
    // Any system name it finds, it's going to put it in data0, then it will sort it        
    const data0 = Array.from(new Set(output.map(({ systemName }) => systemName))).sort();

    // It's going to create a series0 json object which will probably 
    // look like "["systemName": "01","systemName": "02", ...]
    var series0 = {
        name: 'systemName',
        data: data0.map(d => `System ${d}`)
    }

    // The system / name series will be pushed to a Statics object as series 0 for the graph
    Statistics.push(series0);


    // This looks like it's going to iterate over data0, which contains systems,
    // and for each system, iterate over the output 
    // (which is actually input from an API)
    // And if the system name matches is going to add to "acc" (accumulated total
    // for the system if the input (cur.system name) matches the system name 
    // from from data0 (systems)

    // QUESTIONS: 

    // question 1 - where is acc coming from? Is it a dynamic variable? 
    // question 2 - why does it return acc if there's no match? To give the current system 
    // the same total it had previously? 
    // question 3 - why does it return a zero at the end? How does it fit into the picture? 
    // question 4 - Is this getting total objects for the system? 
    const norcaBase = data0.map(systemName => output.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if (cur.systemName === systemName) {
            return acc + cur.sum
        }
        return acc
    }, 0))

  // Create an array of norca data
  const norcaData = {}

  // iterate through the NORCA codes
  NORCA_CODE.forEach((code) => {
     
    // for the current code iterate through the system names
    norcaData[code] = data0.map(systemName => output.reduce((acc, cur) => {
             
            // if the system name and code match, accumulate
             
            if (cur.systemName === systemName && cur.norcaCode === code) {
                return acc + cur.sum
            }
            return acc
        }, 0))
  })


    // iterate through the NORCA Codes

    // question: is "i" an increment?    
    NORCA_CODE.forEach((code, i) => {

        // Push the code and percentage of total into Statistics
        // QUESTION

        // question: where does "d" from? looks the the total for that Norca Code
        Statistics.push({
            name: code,
            data: norcaData[code].map((d, i) => norcaBase[i] ? d / norcaBase[i] : 0)
        })
    })

    // Put the chart-data  entry in filteredData 
    filteredData['chartData'] = {};

    // Put the Statistics into chart data
    filteredData['chartData']['Statistics'] = Statistics;

    // return filtered daa
    return filteredData;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> // what the difference between "{}" and "[]" below?

`{}` creates an object. Javascript objects are similar to maps or dictionaries in other languages and store unordered key/value pairs. `[]` creates an array for storing ordered data.

Taking your questions out of order:

> // question 4 - Is this getting total objects for the system?

Generally speaking, the purpose of `reduce` is to step through an array, and "combine" elements of the array. You provide a function which describes how you want to combine them. Reduce will then step through the array, calling your function for every element of the array. When it calls your function it passes in the value so far (often called the "accumulator"), and the element of the array currently being looked at, and then your function is responsible for returning the new value of the accumulator.

In your specific case, this code is adding up the `.sum` properties of every element in the array who's `systemName`  matches.

> // question 3 - why does it return a zero at the end?

That 0 is the initial value of the accumulator. It's being passed into `reduce`, not returned.

> // question 1 - where is acc coming from?

It's passed in to you by the code for `reduce`. `acc` will be `0` the first time your function is called (see question 3), and on subsequent calls it will be whatever value you returned the last time.

> // question 2 - why does it return acc if there's no match?

Because this code wants the accumulator to not change for that case. Ie, it's not adding anything to it.

> // question: is code an increment?

Not sure what you mean by an increment. `.forEach` will loop over each element of the array and call the function you provided for each of them. The first argument that will be passed in (here named `code`) is the element of the array.

> // question: where does "d" from?

`.map` will call the function you provide once for each element of the array. The first argument is the element of the array. The difference between `.map` and `.forEach` is that with `.map` you are creating a new array, the values of which are whatever you return via your function (`.forEach` pays no attention to what you return).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed, informative answer.  This will help me out greatly going forward. On the increment question, I edited the question to say "is "i" an increment?"

Comment: The second parameter to forEach's function is the index of the element. So the first time your function is called, `i` is 0. Then 1, then 2, etc.